# How does the sliding expiration work in Web API 2 C# using the Jwt

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have added this configuration to the JwtConfig file

```
public static void ConfigureJwt(IServiceCollection service)
{
            service
            .AddAuthentication(options =>{ ... });
            .AddCookie(config =>
            {
                config.SlidingExpiration = true;
                config.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                config.CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>{ ... });
}
```

Creating the token

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken(OpenIdConnectRequest login)
    {
        var token = await _service.AuthAsync(login);
        return Ok(token);
    }
```

The body of the request

```
username=theemail@some.com
&password=password
&grant_type=password or refresh_token
&refresh_token=refreshtoken
&resource=http://localhost
```

How is the token checked and refreshed?

Answer (score 1):

[`SlidingExpiration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.slidingexpiration) will move the expiration time of the cookie each time the cookie is used. So the cookie only expires if it hasn't been used in the time specified by `ExpireTimeSpan` (in your case 15 minutes). Use this to automatically log out a user only after a period of inactivity.

Contrast with with absolute expiry, in which case the cookie would *always* expire after `ExpireTimeSpan`, regardless of how often it was used.